# AS3 Multidimensional array maximum 8 error

Tags: actionscript-3, multidimensional-array, actionscript

Can anyone please help me figure out why I am getting an error when I add a 9th line to this multidimensional array? Thanks!

```
var ColourArray:Array = new Array();
ColourArray[0] = ["0xdc1d28","0xff404b","0xff8b96"]; //RED
ColourArray[1] = ["0x9bb09a","0xc2dcc1","0xe1eee0"]; //PALE
ColourArray[2] = ["0x7a5e66","0x9d8189","0xC3A7AF"]; //BROWN
ColourArray[3] = ["0xB5B5B5","0xD8D8D8","0xffffff"]; //GREY
ColourArray[4] = ["0xDC3B87","0xFF5EAA","0xFFA9F5"]; //PINK
ColourArray[5] = ["0xDC875A","0xFFAA7D","0xFFCFA3"]; //PEACH
ColourArray[6] = ["0x18988F","0x3BBBB2","0x61DDD7"]; //TEAL
ColourArray[7] = ["0x7884DC","0x9BA7FF","0xC1CDFF"]; //LILAC
ColourArray[8] = ["0x0091dc","0x00b4ff","0x25d9ff"]; //BLUE
```

The error is **TypeError: Error #1010: A term is undefined and has no properties.**

It's fine with 8 lines but with 9 it throws up the error. Many thanks!

Comment: Seems odd. Have you tried using ColourArray.push( [ ... ] ); instead?

Comment: Unable to reproduce, give the whole code. And seems error not related to given code. Did it written on timeline? Do you have any other code there?